# Get the selected option using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-select, selected

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup( '''<SELECT>
<option value="1">ONE</option>
<option value="2" selected>TWO</option>
<option value="3">THREE</option>
<option value="4">FOUR</option>
<option value="5">FIVE</option>
</SELECT>''' )

print( soup.findAll('option', selected=True) )
```

The output is:

```
[]
```

I am trying to get the string of the selected option in the example above. But I cannot get the correct option if "selected" is not assigned to anything, it does not have to be necessarily set to True.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup( '''<SELECT>
<option value="1">ONE</option>
<option value="2" selected=''>TWO</option>
<option value="3">THREE</option>
<option value="4">FOUR</option>
<option value="5">FIVE</option>
</SELECT>''' )

print( soup.findAll('option', selected=True) )
```

The output is:

```
[<option selected="" value="2">TWO</option>]
```

Since I am only reading an html file, I don't have any control over that part. Is there a way to work around? I am using BeahutifulSoup 4.1.3 and python 3.3.0

Comment: Works for me with BeautifulSoup 4.1.3; your second example prints `[<option selected="" value="2">TWO</option>]` for me. What version of BeautifulSoup 4 are you using? `selected=True` matches any element that has the *attribute* `selected`, whatever value that attribute has.

Comment: BeahutifulSoup 4.1.3 and python 3.3.0

Comment: What parsers do you have installed? It could be that `lxml` gives different results. It works for me on Python 3.3 with the default HTML parser.

Comment: the second example works for me also since the selected attribute is set.I have the default html parser installed.

Comment: **Both** examples work for me in Python 3.3, I don't see the problem?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in your case, and this actually works for me. Great. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and I don't see why it doesnt work for you. Good luck:)